# Merge hyphenated word from string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

Suppose a string contains "includ- ing" or "joi- ing". How would you search for and join hyphenated words in a string?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
preg_replace('/-\s+/', '', $string);
```

This looks for a `-` followed by one or more whitespace characters and replaces them with the empty string.

Comment: Would this not then result in the string becoming "includ ing" and not actually joining the two words together? It would also catch legitimate hyphens such as ("germ-free").

Comment: @Josh, this would also remove the whitespace, so the result will be "including". If a whitespace is required in order for the replacement to happen, you can use `+` instead of `*`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
// -- Get an array of words splitted with '- '
$splitted = explode('- ', $word);

// -- Rejoined words:
$joined = implode('', $splitted );
```